# How can I see where the properties in application.properties file refer to?

Tags: java, spring-boot, intellij-idea, application.properties

I have some lines inside my application.properties like

```
logging.level.com.website.project.mapper=INFO
```

I want to see where this value is actually used to understand everything about it. Can IntelliJ somehow bring me to where it is used? Or does the programmer have to know all about the properties by himself?

Comment: Such properties are generally used by logging frameworks, `Log4j` for example. Developer is supposed to be aware of them.

Comment: Spring Boot allows you to define log level in your properties. Have a look at the doc : https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-logging.html. You have to look into spring boot code to find where it's used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Press `CTRL+SHIFT+F` in your IntelliJ, switch to Scope directory and set All Places. After that, you can paste a property name in search box. After that, you can see all usage of property.
[image]

Sometimes properties name are assigned to variables, so after when you find it, you need to also check this variable usage.

Answer (score 1):

Spring Boot allows you to define log level in your properties. So `logging.level.com.website.project.mapper=INFO` is equivalent to the following  Logback config :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
  <include resource="org/springframework/boot/logging/logback/base.xml"/>
  <logger name="com.website.project.mapper" level="INFO"/>
</configuration>
```

IntelliJ will offer you completion for package names after `logging.level.`.
So it's used internally, you have to look into Spring Boot code to find where it's used. Have a look at the doc to understand better how it works : https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-logging.html.